# How to use amphp/parallel async call to fetch data from databases and another function to fetch data parallelly

Tags: php, parallel-processing, amphp

amphp/parallel

How to use amphp/parallel async call to fetch data from databases or from another function to fetch data parallelly

i have done research on the github but didn't find anything